# Why is socket.username being set to the first user when a new user connects?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, socket.io, jwt

socket.username being set to the first user to be connected even when a new user connects while other users socket.username is undefined.

I'm trying to use socket middleware to authenticate user. So after successful authentication, I attached the user's username from the database to the socket.username object. I did this so as to use the username to identify each user during the chat. But I discovered that the last logged in user takes the socket.username object of the first user and the other users socket.username is undefined.

The client code just logs only what the server emits without any modification.

So here's the server code:

```
const http = require('http');
const ioServer = require('socket.io');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const app = require('./routes/user.routes');
const mongoConnect = require('../database/mongo');
const User = require('../database/models/user.model');
require('dotenv').config();


const server = http.createServer(app);
// set up the socket server and allow all resource to acces the server
const io = ioServer(server, { cors: { origin: "*" } });


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // Authentication middleware
    io.use(async (socket, next) => {
        try {
            const token = socket.handshake.auth.token;

            // Verify and decode the JWT
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    
            // Get the user information from the database
            const user = await User.findById(decoded.userId);
            if (!user) {
                throw new Error('User not found');
            }
    
            // Attach the user object to the socket
            socket.username = user.username;
            console.log('user', socket.username);
            
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Authentication error', error);
            next(new Error('Authentication error'));
          }
    });

    // Create a Map to track the room for each socket connection
    const socketRoomMap = new Map();
    const socketObject = {};

    // Handle 'join' event when a client joins the chat room
    socket.on('join', (room) => {
        // when a user joins a room, the socket.rooms should be stored
        // in a key value object along with the username
        socket.join(room);
        // console.log(socket.rooms);
        socketRoomMap.set(socket.username, room); // Store the room information for the socket connection
        socket.emit('joined', `You joined ${room}`);
        socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', `${socket.username} joined ${room}`);
    });

    // Handle 'chat message' event when a client sends a message
    socket.on('chat message', (room, message) => {
        io.to(room).emit('chat message', `${socket.username}: ${message}`);
    });

    // Handle 'disconnect' event when a client disconnects
    socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
        const room = socketRoomMap.get(socket.username); // Retrieve the room information for the socket connection
        if (room) {
            socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('user left', `${socket.username} left the chat room`);
            socketRoomMap.delete(socket.username); // Remove the room information for the socket connection
        }
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    mongoConnect()
        .then(() => { })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error);
        });
    console.log('Server started running...');
});

process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
    console.error('Uncaught Exception:', error.stack);
    // Perform any necessary cleanup or logging here
  
    // Gracefully exit the process
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: My guess is that you probably should place your authentication middleware outside of your 'connection' callback, before the `io.on('connection', ...)` line.

Comment: @stolen_orange . Your suggestion improved it. But hasn't fully solved the issue. Now the socket.username of the connection before a new connection is the same as the socket.username of the new connection. For example if user1 logs in, then user2 logs in, they'd both have same socket.username of the user1. Now if user3 logs in, it has the socket.username of user2.

Comment: Hmm, probably tokens are the same then. Have you checked that?
If tokens are similar then the problem could be on the front-end side. Need to be checked.

Comment: @stolen_orange. Thank you. I figured out that that was the problem earlier. I was testing the app on the same machine and because I store the token locally, the token was getting updated with every login.